# System Category Tree View in Backend?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Currently I only know of the standard list module to display categories in the TYPO3 backend. Is there any extension providing a backend module for displaying and managing sys categories, which show the categories in tree view?

Thinking of a web->categories module showing the sys category tree instead of the page tree and then let me modify the category details.

Comment: The problem is that the tree component was (although planned) never abstracted in a way that you could easily re-use it for the category tree. Still it shouldn't be too hard to create such a module using a 3rd party tree component, but I wouldn't know of such an extension.

Comment: Any news on that? Searching for a category "edit" extension, too.